# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07007e in Recycleview Adapter Class

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-recyclerview

Below is my Recycle adapter class, where I'm using recycle view to display books on 3 column. But when I run and compile app crashes with log file of

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07007e
```

Here is the screenshot of same

[image]

Below is my Adapter class  where I am getting above error in line 45 and 21 in onBindViewHolder

```html
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext ;
    private List<Book> mData ;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Book> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view ;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardveiw_item_book,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.tv_book_title.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.img_book_thumbnail.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getThumbnail());
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,Book_Activity.class);

                // passing data to the book activity
                intent.putExtra("Title",mData.get(position).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("Description",mData.get(position).getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("Thumbnail",mData.get(position).getThumbnail());
                // start the activity
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tv_book_title;
        ImageView img_book_thumbnail;
        CardView cardView ;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_book_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_title_id) ;
            img_book_thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_img_id);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_id);


        }
    }
```

Please help me..what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it crash on particular api version (below 21 perhaps?)

Comment: @Pawel I'm testing on API 19 and it crashes ..I haven't tried on above 21

Comment: What kind of drawable are you trying to insert? Is it level-list or selector with vector  items?

Comment: @Pawel This is the source code I was following....https://github.com/aws1994/rv2gridlayout  and here is the youtube link  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SD2t75T5RdY&ab_channel=AwsRh

Comment: those seem to be regular jpg/png images, ensure they are properly imported into your project or try to use different ones.

Comment: @Pawel I did however but  still the problem is same..Ok I'll try  changing images..hope everything will be alright.